# Make is unable to find the functions

Tags: c, linux, shell, makefile, apr

I am trying to compile a C program, while linking the APR library.
I am getting the following error message:

```
cc -g -Wall -pthread -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/local/apr/include/apr-util-1  -L/usr/local/apr/lib -L .aprutil-1 -L .apr-1  devpkg.c bstrlib.o db.o shell.o commands.o   -o devpkg
/tmp/cczC53x5.o: In function `main':
/home/yotam/Dropbox/Development/C/devpkg/devpkg.c:14: undefined reference to `apr_pool_initialize'
/home/yotam/Dropbox/Development/C/devpkg/devpkg.c:15: undefined reference to `apr_pool_create_ex'
/home/yotam/Dropbox/Development/C/devpkg/devpkg.c:29: undefined reference to `apr_getopt_init'
/home/yotam/Dropbox/Development/C/devpkg/devpkg.c:31: undefined reference to `apr_getopt'
db.o: In function `DB_init':
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/db.c:89: undefined reference to `apr_pool_initialize'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/db.c:90: undefined reference to `apr_pool_create_ex'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/db.c:93: undefined reference to `apr_dir_make_recursive'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/db.c:105: undefined reference to `apr_pool_destroy'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/db.c:109: undefined reference to `apr_pool_destroy'
shell.o: In function `Shell_exec':
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:16: undefined reference to `apr_pool_create_ex'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:38: undefined reference to `apr_pool_destroy'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:44: undefined reference to `apr_pool_destroy'
shell.o: In function `Shell_run':
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:55: undefined reference to `apr_procattr_create'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:58: undefined reference to `apr_procattr_io_set'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:62: undefined reference to `apr_procattr_dir_set'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:65: undefined reference to `apr_procattr_cmdtype_set'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:68: undefined reference to `apr_proc_create'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/shell.c:71: undefined reference to `apr_proc_wait'
commands.o: In function `Command_fetch':
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/commands.c:44: undefined reference to `apr_uri_parse'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/commands.c:48: undefined reference to `apr_fnmatch'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/commands.c:51: undefined reference to `apr_fnmatch'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/commands.c:70: undefined reference to `apr_fnmatch'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/commands.c:78: undefined reference to `apr_dir_make_recursive'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/commands.c:84: undefined reference to `apr_fnmatch'
/home/yotam/Development/C/devpkg/commands.c:90: undefined reference to `apr_dir_make_recursive'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [devpkg] Error 1
```

Here is my makefile, it should be able to compile on different computers, where the `PREFIX` variable is the location relative to the computer.
(this program in essence should one day be portable to any OS. for now I would just like to be able to compile it successfully)

```
PREFIX?=/usr/local
LDFLAGS= -L${PREFIX}/apr/lib -L .aprutil-1 -L .apr-1
CFLAGS=-g -Wall -pthread -I${PREFIX}/apr/include/apr-1  -I${PREFIX}/apr/include/apr-util-1

all: devpkg

devpkg: bstrlib.o db.o shell.o commands.o

install: all \
    install -d $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/bin/ \
    install devpkg $(DESTDIR)/$(PREFIX)/bin/

clean: 
    rm -f *.o \
    rm -f devpkg \
    rm -rf *.dSYM
```

I've gone and searched for it myself in the folders and this is what I got:

```
yotam@yotam-HP-ProBook-450://usr$ grep -r apr_pool_initialize .
./local/apr/include/apr-1/apr_pools.h:APR_DECLARE(apr_status_t) apr_pool_initialize(void);
Binary file ./local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.6 matches
Binary file ./local/apr/lib/libapr-1.a matches
Binary file ./local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.5.1 matches
Binary file ./local/apr/lib/libapr-1.so.0.4.5 matches
./local/apr/lib/apr.exp:apr_pool_initialize
```

After the reaserch I did, I clearly understand that this is a linker problem. but I wasn't able to find the command to do the trick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the link option that tells `cc` which library to link with. I'm not sure what `.aprutil-1` and `.apr-1` are in your `LDFLAGS` macro, since you specify them with -L, I will assume they are directories.

However, if you change your line to add the `-l` option to specify the library, it should get you closer.

EDIT: Because the linker is a single pass tool, all the libraries need to be listed *after* the objects, so the symbols will not be optimized away. `LDLIBS` is a typical name for the macro where libraries are specified, and you can tack them on to the end of the compile/link command and it should work.

```
LDFLAGS= -L${PREFIX}/apr/lib -L .aprutil-1 -L .apr-1
LDLIBS=  -lapr-1 -laprutil-1
```

The last two args tell the linker which library names (prepended with *lib* and appended with *.a*) to use. The `-L` option specifies additional directories to search for libraries, it doesn't actually include anything.

Alternatively, you can also set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to your library directories.

You can consult [this site](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/shared-libraries-linux-gcc.html) (among others) as a reference, if you need more help debugging.

Comment: I'd guess the "-L .aprutil-1" and  "-L .apr-1" should probably be omitted since both libs are in apr/lib and that directory is already added to the linker path by the first -L parameter.

Comment: @nimrodm yeah, that was my assumption too, but since I don't know for sure, I left them in. He could be using dot-links...

Comment: just tried that, and it didn't work.
however, the -L . option is something I tried later, and seems like it's just equivelant to what I did before. there was not apperant change

Comment: @YotamAlon Try using the explicit path to those libs with the -L option, and try again. I'm not sure what `${PREFIX}` is resolving to. Is this a location that is relative to your source directory? Update the question with what you try and the results.

Comment: Don't add libraries (`-lfoo`) to LDFLAGS.  They must come _after_ all the objects are listed, with most  UNIX linkers which are single-pass linkers.  GNU make's default variables use `LDFLAGS` to hold linker flags like `-Lfoodir` and `LDLIBS` to hold libraries like `-lfoo`.

Comment: Added some information on the make file. the PREFIX variable can removed essentialy. It is of no real importance, and right now, as far as I can see, of no real effect.

Comment: @YotamAlon yes, that's true. MadScientist is right, you need to add the libraries to the end of the command, after the objects, so it will not optimize out the symbols. If you add the `LDLIBS` macro to your command and use that to specify the libraries, it should work.

Comment: THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH!!!
I have batteling with this for a WEEK!
I was able to compile it and it ran (with errors but that's my fault).
If you come by Israel any time, I'll invite you to a beer.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing LDFLAGS with LDLIBS, as in:

```
LDLIBS=-L${PREFIX}/apr/lib -lapr-1 -pthread -laprutil-1
```

instead of:

```
LDFLAGS=-L${PREFIX}/apr/lib -lapr-1 -pthread -laprutil-1
```

This is because the LDFLAGS variable is meant for non-library options for the linker, whereas in this case you are using libraries.